# Are there any repercussions for my landlord having us sign the wrong lease?

Tags: landlord, tenancy-rules

When we moved in to our current house our landlord said our lease would be a year to year lease. We recently found out that they are selling the building and our housing situation isn't concrete anymore because it turns out our lease is a month to month instead. We asked the landlord to fix the issue and send us a new lease to sign but they are refusing to do so. Is there anything we can do about this situation?

Comment: We do have written proof as well that our lease is meant to be yearly instead of monthly.

Comment: Is that proof dated before or after the signed monthly lease?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your landlord had you sign the wrong lease; it sounds like you signed a lease with terms different than what you agreed to. Absent some really strange circumstances, I think most courts are going to say you should have read the lease and send you on your way.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere It was after the lease was signed. The realtor in charge of selling the building messaged us saying that our lease was incorrect and was meant to be yearly. We were told verbally before signing that it would be yearly as well.

Comment: @bdb484 I understand we should have read the lease more in depth. But is it not bordering on fraud to lie to us about our lease because they knew it'd increase the chances of us signing?

Comment: @TannerS Probably not. Can you prove the landlord was lying and didn't simply give you a month-to-month contract language by mistake? Can you prove the landlord knew you were less likely to sign a month-to-month, which many tenants would actually prefer? Can you provide some good reason why you didn't read your contract?

Comment: @bdb484 I have a message literally saying it is the wrong lease and was meant to be year to year from the realtor hired by the landlord. Is that not proof?

Comment: @TannerS It's evidence that the landlord did something wrong. It's not evidence that the landlord did something wrong on purpose.

Comment: @TannerS - Who told you verbally? The landlord or the realtor? If it was the realtor it's sounding like you might have a case against them (and so might the landlord), but an outcome with a yearly contract with the landlord looks unlikely. If it was the landlord who told you, the lease should have been annotated / amended at time of signing.

Comment: `Is there anything we can do about this situation?` Sure. Option 1 is to try and get the landlord to sign a new lease (I understand you tried this and so far it failed). Option 2 is to find alternative housing arrangements, and once that’s done break the lease (with as much notice period as indicated in the lease you signed). Option 3, pursuing a legal recourse, in a case with such a thin factual basis, is going to be orders of magnitude more expensive and inconvenient than option 2.

Answer (score 8):

### You signed the lease

In general, this is definitive of your intention to have a month-to-month lease.

Any correspondence that you have prior to you signing that you wanted or even agreed on a yearly lease is only evidence that such things formed part of the negotiations but, for whatever reasons, what was ultimately agreed was a month-to-month lease.

If you can prove [misrepresentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misrepresentation) you might be able to get what you want but the usual remedy is recission (ending) of the contract, not a change to the contract. However, given that the type of lease is such a fundamental feature and is usually prominent on the document, proving you were misled rather than agreeing to a month-by-month lease will be difficult.

Comment: How would it be difficult to prove we were misled? We have a message from the building realtor telling us that the lease is wrong and was meant to be monthly.

Comment: @TannerS no, your lease is right - the realtor is wrong. Now do you see the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the state, depends on how much tenant protection you have. Eviction process and notice regulations can be months out. So yes it is not a yearly lease, but depending on state, this may not matter much. Check your local town/city laws, and your state laws for tenant bill of rights.